# Easy way to see a list of all the apps I have installed on my iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, applications

I'm looking for an easy way to see a list of all the apps that are currently installed on my iPhone (running iOS9). In earlier versions of iOS it was possible to just type a '.' into Spotlight and all the apps would come up in a list, but I haven't found a way to do this easily on iOS 9.

Comment: On Settings, scroll down and you should see at the end a last section which features all of your Third Party Apps installed on your current iDevice, found it?

Comment: @Leonardo is correct, there's no other simple way of listing all apps due to Apple's sandboxing of apps.  Apps can't see other apps anymore.

Comment: @fsb that's insane.  It's got to know what's installed; otherwise, spyware might have been installed, and you'd never know.

Comment: This asks about iOS 9 from six years ago.  Has the situation improved for newer versions?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you're using a Mac install "[Apple Configurator](https://support.apple.com/apple-configurator)" (free, from Apple) on [the Mac App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator/id1037126344?mt=12).

> **Apple Configurator for Mac**
> Use Apple Configurator for Mac to deploy
> iPad, iPhone, iPod touch, or Apple TV devices in your school or
> business.

Choose your device while connected via USB (first sign in with your Apple ID) and go to "Actions -> Export -> Info" in the top menu bar.

Then you can choose which details like installed Apps, serial number, etc. you want to export as csv list (you can open in Numbers e.g.)

Answer (score 5):

Since iOS14 in 2020 there is *App Library*. Select the search field at the top to show the apps installed on the device in alphabetical order.

> Swipe left past all your Home Screen pages to see App Library. <sub>[Doc](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/open-apps-iphca3d8b4e3)</sub>
> Tap the search field at the top of the screen [and] scroll up and down to browse the alphabetical list. <sub>[Doc](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/find-your-apps-in-app-library-iph87abad19a)</sub>

[image] from https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/use-app-library-iphone/

Answer (score 4):

There is a way.

Go to

```
Settings > General > Storage and iCloud Usage
```

You should see two buttons labelled ‘Manage Storage’. Click on the first.

This will give you a list of apps installed including if they are in the App Library, offloaded or fully installed and present on the Home Screen / baseboard.

Comment: Not all apps participate in iCloud, so many apps will be missed in this list.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to achieve this so far is by

1. Opening **Settings**
2. **Scrolling down** until the last section, there you'll find a **list** of all the **Apps** installed on your current iDevice

Hope this helped you out!

Comment: This will generally only show you apps that have a settings page configured.  Not all apps will do this.

Comment: @S.Robins Settings/ Siri & search lists apps that Settings/ fails to include.