# Is there a way to retrieve a log with histories on all apps currently or previously installed on an iPad?

Tags: ipad, applications, apple-id, history

Is there a way for me to extract a log with past installation / update information on the apps that are currently / have been installed in an ipad before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use https://privacy.apple.com and request a log of Apple ID details. May take some days.
- In App Store, in the profile section, one can visit all previous purchases and hide/unhide purchases.
- [Easy way to see a list of all the apps I have installed on my iPhone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/244404/easy-way-to-see-a-list-of-all-the-apps-i-have-installed-on-my-iphone) This suggests using Apple Configurator and after plugging in, go to Actions -> export -> information.