# Is it possible to know which apps are installed on other's iPhone?

Tags: iphone

So, it happened that one of my known associates Mr.X installed a certain app on his iPhone. In a few days, one of his family friends somehow came to know that Mr.X installed that app. How could someone possibly know which apps are installed on other's iPhone?

Comment: you can wait for other answers too if you wish... half of the people might be asleep.

Comment: Thanks ankii. I was wondering if there was a way anyone could know what apps are installed on other's iPhone. Specifically any particular app. Makes me raise a brow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were Apple ID information, it would contain only purchases and their dates, not whether the app is currently installed or not. That doesn't seem to be updated in Apple ID information realtime.

- [Easy way to see a list of all the apps I have installed on my iPhone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/244404/easy-way-to-see-a-list-of-all-the-apps-i-have-installed-on-my-iphone)

So direct interaction of the two parties on the app, or in real life can be a possible reason IMO.