# How can I view the list of all apps in the App Library on iOS 15?

Tags: ios, applications

On iOS 14, one could [view the list of all apps in the App Library as follows](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/use-app-library-iphone/):

> [image: on the]

I use an iPhone mini 12 with iOS 15. I don't see the list of all apps in the App Library. Instead, I only see a list of apps if I type at least one letter, but it'll only display the apps containing that letter:

[image]

How can I view the list of all apps in the App Library on iOS 15?

Comment: I’m curious what you’re trying to do. iOS lists all installed apps and if you search for an app, you can delete it or assign it to a spot. What’s the end goal here for you?

Comment: @bmike "OS lists all installed apps" where? My end goal is getting the list of all installed apps.

Comment: iOS 15 has not changed this. Just tap in the search box (don't type a letter).

Comment: @Gilby Thanks, if I tap in the search box, I see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpNUL.jpg No app list.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Swipe left till you get to the App Library. Now tap the search box.

Comment: @Gilby oh, got it, you're right, thanks! I was swiping right instead of swiping left. You're welcome to post an answer and I can add the screenshots.

Comment: I use this [settings app storage method as my preferred manner](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/270522/5472) for enumerating the apps installed and offloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@cachius answer to [Easy way to see a list of all the apps I have installed on my iPhone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/244404/easy-way-to-see-a-list-of-all-the-apps-i-have-installed-on-my-iphone) has the currently correct answer (iOS 14/15).   This also refers to [iOS 14: How to Use the App Library on iPhone](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/use-app-library-iphone/) from MacRumors.

In summary, swipe left to get to the App Library and touch the search box - but don't type anything!

Apple loves to change how we do things, but, in general, old but useful features are still there, but somewhat hidden.